# Grid with equation numbers

Tags: style

Is it possible to have a grid with DisplayFormulaNumbered in mathematica journal stylesheet so i would have something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
eqns = {"eqn1", "eqn2", "eqn3"};
list = {x^2 + 2 x, y^2 + z^2 + 5, z^2}; 

Grid[Thread[{eqns, Style[#, "DisplayFormula"] & /@ list, 
  Item[Style[Row[{"(", #, ")"}], "DisplayFormulaNumbered"], Alignment -> Right] & /@ 
     Range[Length@list]}], 
  Alignment -> Center, ItemSize -> {{5, 10, 3}}, 
  Dividers -> { {True, True, False, True}, {{True}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response as i had no access to the computer till now. I tried your suggestion and it messed up the global numbering for equations. The file can be found in here mathematica-journal.com/submit-article. Can you suggest how to fix it?